# Is it more efficient to store counts from SQL? What are the downsides (synchronization etc.)?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL database with two tables I am interested in querying:

**Users:** Stores information about users such as *userID* etc.

**Map:** A map table containing about 7 million *mapIDs* (an index referring to a physical lat/long on earth).

Many of these *mapIDs* are associated to *userIDs*, so for example user #1 may have 10 *mapIDs* associated with him, user #2 may have 100 etc.

I am interested in knowing what is more efficient/safer/best practice to count how many *mapIDs* belong to a user when I query the database with a *userID*:

**1)** Query the Map table to count how many *mapIDs* belong to the *userID*, OR

**2)** Store the number of *mapIDs* belonging to users in an additional column in the Users table (e.g. *mapCount*), and only query this value (rather than searching the large Maps table each time).

I know option 2 will be faster, but I am worried about potential problems with synchronization etc. For example, every time a user performs an action (e.g. add a *mapID* to his account) I would add the *userID* to the associated *mapID* on the Maps table, and also increment the *mapCount* value in Users so that subsequent searches/actions will be faster. But what if the second query failed for some reason and the *mapCount* field fell out of synch? Is this worth the risk?

What is generally the best thing to do in this situation?

Comment: Ideally you would have Users, Maps, UserMap tables UserMap table acting as the core relationship between the two tables (Users and Maps) that's why we normalize them. if you have the 3 tables counting will be at ease you will not overlap any data in Maps... Maps will just be your map control

Comment: Apologies Chris, I've removed the SQL tag - I'm definitely using MySQL. I will post the code soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building the database, start by using a query to extract the data you want using a query.  You can optimize this query by adding an index on `map(usersId)`.  If the performance is adequate, you are done.

If performance is not sufficient, then you can consider storing the count separately.  Maintaining the count requires triggers on `insert` and `delete` and possibly on `update`.

These triggers will have an effect on performance when adding and modifying data.  This is usually small, but it can be important.  If you are doing bulk-load operations, then you will need to manually handle the summarization values.

All this maintenance is a lot of work, and you should only go down that path if you really need to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not an expert in MySQL so your suggestion of using triggers (but only if the query is inefficient) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing one of the classic database design trade offs: speed vs. accuracy / synchronization. If your DBMS supports triggers, you could denormalize the count into the user table via a trigger on the maps table, in which case you would no longer have to worry about accuracy. This is about as detailed as my answer can be until we know more about your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 reduces the need for an additional write, is easier to implement and maintain, and the read performance difference will be so marginal there's no point in measuring it yet.